# ArangoError: unique constraint violated

Tags: arangodb

My logging picked up an occurrence of the below error.
Its a very simple insert into an edge collection but the _key that was autogenerated already existed in that collection.

Details:
Save in an edge collection via a FOXX app.

*Error: ArangoError: unique constraint violated - in index 0 of type primary over [“_key”]; conflicting key: 13647205*

Arangodb version: 3.3.9 using RocksDB

Comment: Please share the relevant line, where this error happens. The error message is already quite verbose, in that it has detected a unique constraint violation of the `_key` at `insert`.

Comment: Github issue: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/5811

Comment: Unfortunately my FOXX web app only catches the ArangoError description. I can try to sift through all my logs but might take a while as I have 8 servers in my cluster.

Comment: I searched and found the server where the error occurred. Unfortunately, I'm only seeing the error that my FOXX app generated which only included the description of the Arrango level error.
I'm noticing that all the files in the dbserver directory contain:

2018-07-10T00:55:10Z [28621] INFO hangup received, about to reopen logfile
2018-07-10T00:55:10Z [28621] INFO hangup received, reopened logfile

(I'm using the arango helper for my cluster)